# Pandas choose the latest datetime within an interval of 5 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, intervals

I am trying to choose the latest time value for a measurement type within an interval of 5 minutes.

```
data = [
        ["2017-01-03T10:04:45", "A", "35.79"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:01:18", "B", "98.78"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:09:07", "A", "35.01"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:03:34", "B", "96.49"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:02:01", "A", "35.82"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:05:00", "B", "97.17"],
        ["2017-01-03T10:05:01", "B", "95.08"]
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["timestamp", "measurement_type", "measurement_value"])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['measurement_value'] = df['measurement_value'].astype(float)
```

My DataFrame df:

| timestamp | measurement_type | measurement_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-03 10:04:45 | A | 35.79 |
| 2017-01-03 10:01:18 | B | 98.78 |
| 2017-01-03 10:09:07 | A | 35.01 |
| 2017-01-03 10:03:34 | B | 96.49 |
| 2017-01-03 10:02:01 | A | 35.82 |
| 2017-01-03 10:05:00 | B | 97.17 |
| 2017-01-03 10:05:01 | B | 95.08 |

the desired output ist:

| timestamp | measurement_type | measurement_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-03 10:05:00 | A | 35.79 |
| 2017-01-03 10:10:00 | A | 35.01 |
| 2017-01-03 10:05:00 | B | 97.17 |
| 2017-01-03 10:10:00 | B | 95.08 |

so it should be roundep up to the 5 minutes the timestamp is within. And if the timestamp is equal to the interval boundery it should be considered for the current interval
for example:
| 2017-01-03 10:05:00 | B                | 97.17             |
belongs to 10:05:00 and not 10:10:00

I found this

```
df.groupby(["measurement_type", pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="5min", offset="1sec")])["timestamp"].max()
```

which puts out:

```
measurement_type  timestamp          
SPO2              2017-01-03 10:00:01   2017-01-03 10:05:00
                  2017-01-03 10:05:01   2017-01-03 10:05:01
TEMP              2017-01-03 10:00:01   2017-01-03 10:04:45
                  2017-01-03 10:05:01   2017-01-03 10:09:07
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but I have the following problems with this:

1. the datetime is rounded off but I need it rounded up (I solved this by just adding 5 minutes to each datetime but maybe there is a better option?)
2. I used offset="1sec" so the 10:05:00 is considered for the 10:00:00 interval and not the 10:05:00 (keep in mind this is correct because the timestamps are getting rounded off but I actually need them rounded up). I think I will just subtract one second from the timestamp again to get rid of the 01.
3. the output is a Series where the measurement_value gets lost. Is it possible to keep the measurement_value column with correspondig value for the chosen timestamp? I mean like getting a DataFrame like in the desired output

I hope I formulated my question in a understandable way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `5min` freq grouper with parameters `closed='right'` and `label='right'`, then sort the dataframe on `timestamp` then `groupby` and aggregate with `last` to select the row with latest timestamp in the 5 min intervals

```
g = pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='5min', label='right', closed='right')
df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby(['measurement_type', g]).last().reset_index()
```

Result

```
  measurement_type           timestamp  measurement_value
0                A 2017-01-03 10:05:00              35.79
1                A 2017-01-03 10:10:00              35.01
2                B 2017-01-03 10:05:00              97.17
3                B 2017-01-03 10:10:00              95.08
```